# sqlite not creating table in command line

Tags: sqlite, csv, import

I am new to SQLite and I have been trying to create a table in a database by importing a .csv file.

I type in the following commands:

```
sqlite>.mode csv

sqlite> .import testdata.csv testtable
```

No table is created and it returns the following line:

> Usage: .import FILE TABLE

My machine is running Windows 10 and I have SQLite version 3.21

Comment: Did you try using the full file path? For example c:/downloads/testdata.csv

Answer (score 3):

Quote the file name:

```
sqlite> .import "testdata.csv" testtable
```